# Enabling async rendering in flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, firefox

Regarding bug in firefox:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1307108

Flash is not working properly, strange stuff happend(Mouse events are dispatching with time lag, they are dispatching by themselves, etc.). Solution is by link from firefox: **enable async rendering.**

> There is also a separate functional regression caused by Adobe in bug
>   1301486 which would be fixed by enabling async rendering.

Is something like that possible to do in Flash, in AS3 code ? When we set this in option in firefox(dom.ipc.plugins.asyncdrawing.enabled) it solve the problem.

Thank you in advance for any answer
Egid

Comment: Does it make a difference when you choose one of the 3 "hardware acceleration" options before compiling your SWF? Did you try setting GPU to "enabled" in the html embed options? Anyways this sounds like a Firefox prgram issue not an AS3 API issue so don't expect such an option as `plugins.asyncdrawing.enabled` (and not even a possible equivalent). Is this issue with latest version of Firefox? Only Mozilla can fix it...

Answer (score 0):

Some flash applications work slow in Firefox 49.0.2 on Windows.
Setting the wmode to "gpu" improves performance.